# Vba - Gráfico + Mostrar Detalhe

Tags: vba, gráfico

Boa Tarde!

Alguém consegue ajudar com esse código.

Estou tentando gravar uma macro que quando eu clicar na série de dados do gráfico, ele abra os casos em uma nova aba (Como faz o mostrar detalhe)

Ao gravar o código as linhas gravadas são essas:

```
Sub Macro2()

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 6").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True


End Sub
```

Só que quando vou depurar o código ou até rodar direto, fica selecionado a linha "Selection.ShowDetail = True" e aparece a seguinte mensagem:
Erro em tempo de execução '438'

O objeto não aceita esta prioridade ou metodo

Alguém consegue ajudar?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

A propriedade "Show Detail (Mostrar Detalhe)" é exclusiva de tabelas dinâmicas. Caso o gráfico em questão não seja um Gráfico Dinâmico (ou seja, criado a partir de uma Tabela Dinâmica, através da opção Gráfico Dinâmico), essa propriedade não irá funcionar e, por isso, ocorre o erro 438.

Por favor, tente gravar essa mesma macro a partir de um gráfico dinâmico e confira se funciona. Se não der certo, me avise aqui mostrando os passos realizados.

At.te,

Comment: Oi Andréa, obrigado pelo retorno. 

Segui a sua orientação e não funcionou!

O gráfico já correspondia a uma tabela dinâmica, mas fiz uma base teste 
1) selecionando os casos da Base, selecionando o Menu inserir, gráfico dinâmico, escolhendo gráfico dinâmico, movendo a dinâmica criada para outra aba e gráfico para outra aba, gravei a mesma macro e não deu certo

2) selecionando os casos da Base, selecionando o Menu inserir, gráfico dinâmico, escolhendo gráfico dinâmico e tabela dinâmica, movendo a dinâmica criada para outra aba e gráfico para outra aba, gravei a mesma macro e não deu

Answer (score 0):

Olhando a documentação e a sua resposta, o que pode ter ocorrido é que a opção "Habilitar a exibição de detalhes" está desabilitada.

Para conferir isso e, eventualmente, habilitar novamente essa opção, faça o seguinte:

- Clique em qualquer campo da tabela dinâmica
- Na guia **Analisar** na faixa de opções, no grupo Tabela Dinâmica, clique em **Opções**.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Em **Opções** da Tabela Dinâmica, clique na guia **Dados**.
- Em Dados da Tabela Dinâmica, marque ou desmarque a caixa de seleção **Habilitar a exibição de detalhes** para desabilitar ou habilitar essa opção.

Feito isso, teste a macro novamente. Se não for esse o problema ou se mesmo assim não funcionar, me avise aqui.

Comment: Oi Andréa tudo bem? Em dados da tabela dinâmica a caixa de seleção da opção **Habilitar o recurso Mostrar Detalhes** já estava marcada. Desmarquei a caixa e rodei a macro novamente e não deu certo, Marquei novamente e rodei de novo e também não foi.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Acredito que agora vai!

Ao invés de selecionar o gráfico para mostrar os detalhes, experimente gravar a macro selecionando diretamente a tabela dinâmica, no caso, em alguma linha dos campos de Valor.

Eu experimentei e funcionou.

Se ainda assim não der certo, me avise.

Comment: Oi Andréa, agora foi! 

O que fiz para poder funcionar foi criar um botão transparente para ficar em cima da linha da barra ou do número quando o gráfico não era de colunas, aí direcionava para a tabela dinâmica, com isso o código Selection.ShowDetail = True abre os casos. 

Muito obrigado por toda a atenção, desculpe não ter retornado antes, mas tive que gravar 60 macros.